# How to convert raster to polyline in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster-conversion

How can I convert raster (stream segments result of a watershed analysis) to vector polylines, preferably shapefile. In ArcGIS this is easily acomplished with the Raster to Polyline tool.  I only see Polygonize (Raster to Vector) tool under the Raster -> Conversion menu.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using QGIS with GRASS support you can:

1. Use [r.reclass](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.reclass.html) reclass all the stream segments to 1 and everything
   else to nodata.
2. use [r.to.vect](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.to.vect.html) to convert the value of 1 to line, and line is default output. If one says you need GRASS 7 just use the other.

[image]

Comment: Just run that and it crashed. I will download grass itself and try in GRASS. I was trying version 7 on a different machine and just about every function in GRASS was crashing so I am hoping that in Windows 7 i will have better luck.  So far my QGIS/GRASS experience is such - constant crashing.

Comment: Just use osgeo4w

Comment: Hi, how can I change 0 values to no data by using r.reclass? 0 = nodata is flagged as an unvalid reclass rule

Comment: For 0 to equal nodata try: 0 = NULL
Documentation is also linked in the answer.

Comment: I tried this and I got an error "Warning: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows." What does this mean?

Comment: @jsilverman thats not an error, just a warning

Comment: This question [Converting raster to vector by generating center lines?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251360/converting-raster-to-vector-by-generating-center-lines) may help