# Colour-based shapefile generation from image

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

Suppose I want to extract the road network of Zambia, and I retrieved the following image:

[image]

The conventional strategy would be to georeference it (e.g. using GDAL/QGIS) and then manually draw a line shapefile over the green lines on the map.

But would it be possible to automate the process based on colour (i.e. tell the software to draw lines wherever a certain RGB colour is found)?

Comment: The answer to almost any IT-related "Is it possible"-question is: **Yes**

Comment: I generally think this is possible with some effort and good scripting (Use `imagemagick` or `gdal_calc` to extract dark green and then `r.thin` from grass to make lines out of it). But this will not be perfect and a lot of manual work needs to be done. Results might be better using some deep learning. Although the question is interesting, it is far too broad for GIS SE. You should just try and ask more specific questions when you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to georeference the raster. The pixels in your image will have varying RGB values that determine what color appears on the map. You can extract these values using python as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/how-can-i-read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python or https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/extracting-pixel-values-of-an-image-in-python/.

You could use these RGB values to make a binary (road - not road) classification where for a certain R, G, and B (of the green road color) set the pixel value to 1. It might be necessary to use a tolerance for each RGB value since the road pixels may be slightly different green values when you zoom in really close.

Then the binary classification can be converted to a polyline such that where the binary classification = 1, make a polyline. This can be done using ArcGIS Raster to Polyline or there's a QGIS GRASS version described here: [How to convert raster to polyline in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174707/how-to-convert-raster-to-polyline-in-qgis). You will probably need to do a little manual tidying of the output polylines (ex. delete the legend items, or the HQ dots).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It would be great to write a Phython script to automatise this (and then just change the R G B values).